# How to fix when I'm editing a data in datagridview in another form all the content is being cleared?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, datagridview, addition

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
        'Try
        If Not IsNumeric(txtUnit.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Enter Unit Number.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "LASAC")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf txtName.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter Name.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "LASAC")
            Exit Sub

```
    End If

    If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
        conn.ConnectionString = constring
        conn.Open()
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblBilling(Unit,FullName) VALUES(" & CInt(txtUnit.Text) & ",'" & Replace(txtName.Text, "'", "''") & "')"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteReader()
        conn.Close()
        MsgBox("Sucessfully added", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "New")


        NewBtn.PerformClick()


    Else
        conn.ConnectionString = constring
        conn.Open()
        sSQL = "UPDATE tblBilling SET FullName = '" & Replace(txtName.Text, "'", "''") & "',  Unit = " & CInt(txtUnit.Text) & " WHERE 'ID = '" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & ""
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteReader()
        conn.Close()
        MsgBox("Successfully Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")


    End If
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    showmember()
    txtName.Enabled = False
    txtUnit.Enabled = False
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Save")
    'End Try


End Sub

Private Sub NewBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewBtn.Click
    txtName.clear()
    txtUnit.Clear()
    txtUnit.Enabled = True
    txtName.Enabled = True
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DeleteBtn.Click
    If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count <> 0 Then
        If MsgBox("You are deleting a confidential data?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Statement Deleting") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            conn.ConnectionString = constring
            conn.Open()
            'MsgBox(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value)
            sSQL = "DELETE FROM tblBilling WHERE ID = " & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & ""
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteReader()
            conn.Close()
            'MsgBox("Data successfully delete", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "DELETE")
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
            NewBtn.PerformClick()
            'Else
            '    MsgBox("Delete Canceled")
        End If
    End If
    showmember()

    txtName.Enabled = False
    txtUnit.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Comment: may you post the `DataSource` of `DataGridView1` and also where is `debts`? a column or a field?

Comment: how can i post it? im just new here. sorry. that is my code for the update and save.

Comment: my datagridview is being cleared when im adding a data in my datagridview and after i close it and open it the all showed up. sorry for the english.

Comment: `debts` is a column? and how you assign your data to `DataGridView1`, and the code in `frmStatement.showmember()'

Comment: If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
            conn.ConnectionString = constring
            conn.Open()
            sSQL = "INSERT INTO tblBilling(Unit,FullName) VALUES(" & CInt(txtUnit.Text) & ",'" & Replace(txtName.Text, "'", "''") & "')"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteReader()
            conn.Close()
            MsgBox("Sucessfully added", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "New")


            NewBtn.PerformClick()

Comment: sorry i post wrong codes. ^ that is the code

Comment: Else
            conn.ConnectionString = constring
            conn.Open()
            sSQL = "UPDATE tblBilling SET FullName = '" & Replace(txtName.Text, "'", "''") & "',  Unit = " & CInt(txtUnit.Text) & " WHERE 'ID = '" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & ""
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, conn)
            cmd.ExecuteReader()
            conn.Close()
            MsgBox("Successfully Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")


        End If
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        showmember()
        txtName.Enabled = False
        txtUnit.Enabled = False

Comment: and how can i also subtract and add a amount from another form to another form for datagridview?? :(

Comment: I think you should post your code in question and one problem for one question if not related

Comment: i posted it already. my problem is when i delete and add in datagridview everything is disapearing then after i close and open they appeard.

Comment: in your comment, you have a code `DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()`, but not exists in your question, that's may the problem. If that is the case, please update your code in question.

Comment: slr. sir i already updated my codes. as what i told you awhile ago. when i add a content in my datagridview all the data is being cleard and after i close it and open again they are there. same in delete button. thanks :(

Comment: You should not remove your problem in question, plus the formatting incorrect

Comment: oh sorry. im newbie. what should i do with my program?

Answer (score 0):

You have a code to clear all your rows, but didn't to retrieve the data bank

```
Else
    conn.ConnectionString = constring
    conn.Open()
    sSQL = "UPDATE tblBilling SET FullName = '" & Replace(txtName.Text, "'", "''") & "',  Unit = " & CInt(txtUnit.Text) & " WHERE 'ID = '" & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & ""
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, conn)
    cmd.ExecuteReader()
    conn.Close()
    MsgBox("Successfully Updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")


End If

' you have clear all your rows here
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
showmember()
txtName.Enabled = False
txtUnit.Enabled = False
'Catch ex As Exception
'    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Save")
'End Try
```

Comment: when i also remove showmember it does not clear the my datagridview but when i add new data, my data that been save is not showing in my datagridview. :((

Comment: @GILNISHIWAKI because you didn't retrieve your data from database again.

Comment: can i loop that or what should i do?

Comment: @GILNISHIWAKI just assign the data to `datagrid` after you clear all rows

Comment: how can i asign? tru the connection of the datagrid?

Comment: does those code written by you? if not, you may need to study it hardly, I think SO not for asking how to code